# Geoserver legend spacing

Tags: raster, geoserver, cartography, legend, parameters

I want to know if is possible to change spacing of a normal (not raster) legend in Geoserver:

[image]

I need to add more space between the squares and the text.

There are `dx,dy,mx,my` parameters but they only work for Raster Layers

Answer (score 3):

Mauro Bartolomeoli is proposing new vendor options to control margin around labels just this week:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/WMS-GetLegendGraphic-td5293025.html

So, I would expect to find this functionality in a release in the next few months (if I had to guess, maybe 2.9.4 in January 2017, maybe 2.10.1 in December 2016)

Answer (score 2):

The Geoserver manual is a [good spot](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html#) to check out more information.

You could use the GetLegendGraphic to change the normal legend graphics.

> The GetLegendGraphic operation itself is optional for an SLD-enabled WMS. It provides a general mechanism for acquiring legend symbols, beyond the LegendURL reference of WMS Capabilities. Servers supporting the GetLegendGraphic call might code LegendURL references as GetLegendGraphic for interface consistency. Vendor-specific parameters may be added to GetLegendGraphic requests and all of the usual OGC-interface options and rules apply. No XML-POST method for GetLegendGraphic is presently defined.

These two parameters can be specified for Vector graphics, as in your case.

> WIDTH  Optional    This gives a hint for the width of the returned graphic in pixels. Vector-graphics can use this value as a hint for the level of detail to include.
>
> HEIGHT     Optional    This gives a hint for the height of the returned graphic in pixels.

Furthermore,

> GeoServer allows finer control over the legend appearance via the vendor parameter LEGEND_OPTIONS. The general format of LEGEND_OPTIONS is the same as FORMAT_OPTIONS,

You could get more details from the [Geoserver manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html#controlling-legend-appearance-with-legend-options)

Comment: Thanks, I found that article before asking, but there isn't any documented way to do what I'm trying to do

Comment: You just need to play around with the getlegendgraphic request, @IAmJulianAcosta. Perhaps add the request you're using now in your question?